# Python subprocess does not work with complex linux commands

Tags: python, linux, awk, sed

I have a command in Linux which gives me following output:

> 1425463080: 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000000000e+00
>   1425463085: 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000000000e+00
>   1425463090: 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000000000e+00
>   1425463095: 0.0000000000e+00 0.0000000000e+00
>   ...

To make it more human readable I am using awk command as follows:

```
my command | awk 'NR > 2 {printf "%s %0.2f %0.2f\n", $1, $2, $3;}'
```

Now to remove extra **:**, I am using sed as follows:

```
my command | awk 'NR > 2 {printf "%s %0.2f %0.2f\n", $1, $2, $3;}' | sed 's/://g'
```

With this I get following output as expected:

> 1425463715 0.16 0.42
>   1425463720 0.16 0.42
>   1425463725 0.16 0.42
>   ...

Now I want to run above command through Python. But I am facing so many problems while running it through Python subprocess module. For example I am facing following error:

> ('', 'awk: NR > 2 {printf "%s %0.2f %0.2f\nawk:                ^ unterminated string\n')

Even if I assign command as:

```
cmd = """ my command | awk 'NR > 2 {printf "%s %0.2f %0.2f\n", $1, $2, $3;} """
subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...)
```

... still it does not work.

Please let me know if my Linux command is correct. If yes then how can I execute it through Python subprocess.

Comment: Did you set `shell=True`? Without that you are trying to run a single executable named `my command' | awk 'NR > 2 {...etc..`

Comment: Yes, tried with shell=True as well

Comment: You're missing the opening quote around `my command`

Comment: @Avinash True but I wanted to handle that on Linux cmd level

Comment: Your sample `cmd` contains a stray `'` single quote before the first `|`. Also, the `\n` is not escaped.

Comment: And you are missing the trailing quote on the awk snippet

Comment: Oops, sorry that was typo error. Corrected extra \'

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `\n` escape sequence; Python interprets that too; you are also missing a closing `'` single quote in the awk command:

```
cmd = """ 'my command' | awk 'NR > 2 {printf "%s %0.2f %0.2f\\n", $1, $2, $3;}' """
```

or use a raw string:

```
cmd = r""" 'my command' | awk 'NR > 2 {printf "%s %0.2f %0.2f\n", $1, $2, $3;}' """
```

Note that Python is perfectly capable to do this work too, removing the need to use an extra shell binary in between to interpret the shell syntax.